# Powershell - click submit button on HTML code

Tags: powershell

I tried many different ways to click submit button on HTML code, but always got error.

```
<form action="abnormal-times.aspx" method="post">
Time out Minutes <input name="Minutes" style="width: 100px;" value="5"> Minutes.<br>
Time out Hours <input name="Minutes" style="width: 100px;" value="2"> Hours.
<input onclick="submit()" type="button" value="submit">
```

With my powershell code:

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate("http://localhost.com")

while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) { start-sleep -s 1 }

$Link = $ie.Document.getElementsByValue("submit")
$Link.click()
```

But always popup error.

```
Method invocation failed because [mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass] doesn't contain a method
 named 'getElementsByValue'.
At C:\temp\Untitled1.ps1:28 char:42
+ $Link = $ie.Document.getElementsByValue <<<< ("submit")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (getElementsByValue:String) [], Run 
   timeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\temp\Untitled1.ps1:29 char:14
+ $Link.click <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (click:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Now I changed into this:

```
$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("button") | where-object {$_.type -eq "submit"}
$Link.click()
```

The error came out:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Work_Server\Desktop\joseph.ps1:29 char:10
+ $go.click <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (click:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: The object doesn't have a method `getElementsByValue`, so you can't call it. You can verify that by running `$ie.Document | Get-Member`. Use `$ie.Document.getElementsByName` or `$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName` instead and filter the results with `Where-Object`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **tag name** of your button is `input`, and the **type** is `button`. Try this.

```
$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | where-object {$_.type -eq "button"}
$Link.click();
```